# What is the right way to clean up $title before wp_insert_post?

Tags: permalinks, wp-insert-post

I am using a function to insert some post data and i am having problems with the title/title - slug. The title is random selected from an array, some title have `?`, `!` or `.` (dots)

I notice `wp_insert_post` doesn't clean up the title so in the title slug (permalink) i see the `?`, `!` or dots. How can i fix this? Any WP built-in function?

This is my function

```
function my_add_post($title, $content){
  // Create post object
  $title = str_replace('.','',$title);
  $title = str_replace('?','',$title);
  $my_post = array(
    'post_title'    => $title,
    'post_content'  => $content,
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_author'   => 1,
    'post_category' => array(1)
  );

  // Insert the post into the database
  wp_insert_post( $my_post );   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any WP built-in function?

Yes, [**`sanitize_title`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title).

Comment: tx, i am also trying wp_strip_all_tags

Comment: @alex `wp_strip_all_tags` is useless. WordPress already strips all tags when you use `sanitize_title`.